# Jasmine tests and ES6 module transpiler

Tags: javascript, jasmine, ecmascript-6, code-translation

I have some issue with [ES6 module transpiler](https://github.com/esnext/es6-module-transpiler) and my Jasmine tests, here it:

```
import Foo from '../dist/Foo.js';

describe('Test Foo', ()=>{
    let foo

    beforeEach(()=>{
        foo = new Foo()
    })

    it('Foo should create new instance', ()=>{
        expect(foo instanceof Foo).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

and my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('tests:concat', function(){
    return gulp.src(['spec/*.js', '!spec/all.spec.js'])
               .pipe(concat('all.spec.js'))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('spec/'))
})

gulp.task('tests:es6', ['tests:concat'], function(){
    return gulp.src('spec/all.spec.js')
               .pipe(es6ModuleTranspiler({ type: 'cjs' }))
               .pipe(es6transpiler())
               .pipe(gulp.dest('spec/'))
})

gulp.task('tests', ['tests:es6'], function(){
    gulp.src('spec/all.spec.js')        
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('spec/'))
})
```

and when I try to run this task

> gulp tests

I got

> ```
>     throw err
>          ^
> ```
>
> Error: no writecb in Transform class

So I found that error throw globals such `describe` in my tests, because if I add this line:

```
let describe, beforeEach, it, expect
```

compilation complete without problems

In documentation for ES6 module transpiler no info how allow globals. How resolve it?

Comment: Try https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs, and import import required functions manually.

Comment: @dentuzhik thanks but do I really need a loader just for that? ES6 classes work basically in any web browser today